# How can I reference 2 different columns in 2 different tables simultaneously

Tags: database, oracle

This is an assignment and I have been given this diagram for reference - https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOJzY.jpg

There are other tables that I will include but the issue seems to be with the tables `section` and `time_slot`. In the diagram, they reference each other but I don't know how to. Any comments are helpful! I am using Oracle btw, here is the code -

```
create table department (
       dept_name varchar(15) primary key,
       building varchar(10),
       budget int
);

create table instructor (
       id varchar(10) primary key,
       name varchar(15) not null,
       dept_name varchar(20) not null
            references department(dept_name) on delete cascade,
       salary int not null
);

create table course (
       course_id varchar(10) primary key,
       title varchar(10),
       dept_name varchar(15)
            references department(dept_name) on delete cascade,
       credits int
);

create table classroom (
        building varchar(10) not null,
        room_no varchar(5) not null,
        capacity int not null,
        primary key (building, room_no)
);

create table section (
        course_id varchar(10) not null
                references course(course_id),
        sec_id varchar(10) not null, 
        semester varchar(10) not null,
        year varchar(10) not null,
        building varchar(10) not null
            references classroom(building),
        room_no varchar(5) not null
            references classroom(room_no),
        time_slot_id varchar(5) not null
            references time_slot(time_slot_id),
        primary key (course_id, sec_id, semester, year)
);

create table time_slot (
        time_slot_id varchar(5) not null
            references section(time_slot_id),
        day varchar(10) not null,
        start_time date not null,
        end_time date not null,
        primary key (time_slot_id, day, start_time)
);   

create table teaches (
       id varchar(10) primary key
            references instructor(id) on delete cascade,
       course_id varchar(15) not null
            references section(course_id),
       sec_id varchar(5) not null
            references section(sec_id),
       semester varchar(15)
            references section(semester),
       year int not null
            references section(year)
);

create table student (
       id varchar(10) not null primary key,
       name varchar(20) not null,
       dept_name varchar(15) not null
            references department(dept_name) on delete cascade,
       tot_cred int not null
);

create table advisor (
       s_id  varchar(10) primary key
            references student(id) on delete cascade,
       i_id varchar(6)
            references instructor(id) on delete cascade
);

create table prereq (
        course_id varchar(10) 
            references course(course_id) on delete cascade,
        prereq_id varchar(10) 
            references course(course_id) on delete cascade,
        primary key (course_id, prereq_id)
);

create table takes (
        id varchar(10) not null
            references student(id) on delete cascade,
        course_id varchar(10) not null
            references section(course_id) on delete cascade,
        sec_id varchar(10) not null
            references section(sec_id) on delete cascade,
        semester varchar(10) not null
            references section(semester) on delete cascade,
        year int not null
            references section(year) on delete cascade,
        grade varchar(10) not null,
        primary key (id, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade)
);
```

This is the output -
Table created.

Table created.

Table created.

Table created.

ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: You have three errors. What exact error is the issue and why? Create tables step by step and stop on the first error. Resolve it, then go ahead.

Comment: The other 2 errors and because of the first error. The first error means that the table is not created, therefore, the next 2 tables that reference that table will not work which results in the next 2 errors.

Comment: Any reason you cannot create table with constraint and later add constraint. This is the only way given few tables you have are self-referential. So create the underlying table and then in your script add alter table add constraint.